# Xamarin Forms list contacts and phone numbers

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm creating an application that should list contacts and contacts phones. The contact list I can do, but I am being unable to list the phone numbers associated with a particular contact.
I have been leaning across the network to find a workable solution to my problem but I am being unable to find the solution.

This is the code that reads and lists the contacts.

```
public List<Contato> ListaContato()
    {
        var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;

        string[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoId };

        var cursor = Context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        var contactList = new List<Contato>();

        if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                Contato contato = new Contato();
                Telefone telefone = new Telefone();

                contato.Id = cursor.GetInt(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[0]));
                contato.NomeContato = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[1]));
                contato.FotoContato = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[2]));

                contato.Telefone = CarregarTelefone(contato.Id.ToString());

                contactList.Add(contato);
            }
            while (cursor.MoveToNext());
        }

        return contactList;
    }
```

This other method is to make the listing of phone numbers associated with a contact.

```
public List<Telefone> CarregarTelefone(string contactId)
    {
        //ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.SearchDisplayNameKey
        var cursor = Context.ContentResolver.Query(Phone.ContentUri, new String[] { Phone.Number }, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Identity.IdentityColumnId + "=" + contactId, null, null);
        //var c = Context.ContentResolver.Query(Phone.ContentUri, new String[] { Phone.Number }, Phone.ContentItemType + "=" + Phone.TYPE_MOBILE + " and " + Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId, null, null);


        List<Telefone> litel = new List<Telefone>();

        //if (cursor.MoveToNext())
        //{
        //    Telefone tele = new Telefone();
        //    tele.NumeroTelefone = cursor.GetString(0);
        //    litel.Add(tele);
        //}

        while (cursor.MoveToNext())
        {
            Telefone tele = new Telefone();
            tele.NumeroTelefone = cursor.GetString(0);
            litel.Add(tele);
        }

        return litel;
    }
```

I have used this code as a reference, but it does not serve me fully.

> cursor = contentResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
>                   new String[]{Phone.NUMBER},
>                   Phone.TYPE + "=" + Phone.TYPE_MOBILE+" and "+Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId, null, null);

The code is contained in this link: [ContentResolver.Query()](https://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.content.ContentResolver/query)

How do I, then, be able to list all the phone numbers of a contact in my xamarin application?

---

Good night people!
Regarding the issue of discovering the phone's label (mobile, home, work etc) I want to say that I have already found the solution and I am sharing here with you.

```
public List<Telefone> CarregarTelefone(string contactId)
    {
        var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;

        string[] projection = { Phone.Number, CommonColumns.Type };

        var cursor = Context.ContentResolver.Query(Phone.ContentUri, projection, ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.ContactId + "=" + contactId, null, null);

        List<Telefone> litel = new List<Telefone>();

        if (cursor != null)
        {
            while (cursor.MoveToNext())
            {
                Telefone tele = new Telefone();
                tele.NumeroTelefone = cursor.GetString(0);
                tele.Etiqueta = CarregarEtiqueta(int.Parse(cursor.GetString(1)));
                litel.Add(tele);
            }
        }

        cursor.Close();

        return litel;
    }
```

Now I still need help solving the issue of listing a contact's groups (Family, Work, Schoolmates, Teachers etc). I have looked at some things on the web, but I have not yet succeeded. Any tip is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm creating an application that should list contacts and contacts phones. The contact list I can do, but I am being unable to list the phone numbers associated with a particular contact. I have been leaning across the network to find a workable solution to my problem but I am being unable to find the solution.

You can't retrieve the phone numbers according to `contactId` because you are using the wrong filter string:

`ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Identity.IdentityColumnId + "=" + contactId`

The correct filter looks like this:

`ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + "=" + contactId`

So `CarregarTelefone` should looks like this:

```
public List<Telefone> CarregarTelefone(string contactId)
{
    var cursor = this.ContentResolver.Query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri, new string[] { Phone.Number }, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + "=" + contactId, null, null);

    List<Telefone> litel = new List<Telefone>();

    while (cursor.MoveToNext())
    {
        Telefone tele = new Telefone();
        tele.NumeroTelefone = cursor.GetString(0);
        litel.Add(tele);
    }

    return litel;
}
```

**Update:**

For search of etiquette, you can add a `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.Type` column to the search columns:

```
var cursor = this.ContentResolver.Query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri, new string[] { Phone.Number, Phone.InterfaceConsts.Type }, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + "=" + contactId, null, null);
```

It will give you an int value.You can compare the int with the [type table](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html) to get the current type of phone.

Comment: Thank you!
That really solved my problem.
Now, without wanting to abuse your goodwill, do you have any idea how I can list the groups to which a specific contact belongs?

Comment: Another thing: How do I find out the etiquette of a phone number (mobile, landline, work)?

Comment: By etiquette, you mean something like `Mobile\Home\Work\Work Fax`?

Comment: Yes! Mobile, home, fax etc.